# Difference among 走去 vs 走路 vs 步行?

Tags: mandarin

Are 走去, 走路, and 步行 interchangeable? Specifically, are they all valid variations of saying "to walk?"?

For instance, are all these identical?

- 我們走去了三分鐘
- 我們走路了三分鐘
- 我們步行了三分鐘

Comment: re：走去，walk over (to) 去 functions as complement of direction, e.g. (bkrs) 照这个方向走去, 向河边走去,他们沿着声音走去, combining with a complement of duration seems unusual, 我們走去了三分鐘 "we walked over for 3 minutes"? to say e.g. "it took us 3 minutes to walk over (to the river)" could say 我们用三分钟 (向河边)走去

Comment: 我们走去学校=我们走路去学校=我们步行去学校, 我们走了三分钟=我们步行了三分钟.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

我們走去了三分鐘 and 我們走路了三分鐘 are unnatural. The common way to say it is 我們走了三分鐘.

走去 is not a good set. We don't really use it.

More often, 走路 is more like a gerund, and 走 alone is usually used as a verb. You can say 我們走路走了三分鐘.

步行 could be used as a verb as it's in your example.

So, these sentences convey the same thing:

> 我們走了三分鐘.
>
> 我們走路走了三分鐘.
>
> 我們步行了三分鐘.

Answer (score 1):

走去(walk to) is followed by "somewhere" or "do sth".

> 走去车站
>
> 走去买衣服

"走去了三分鐘" doesn't make sense

走路 is a V+O structure, in which "了" should always be put directly after the V.
So it's 走了三分鐘路, not 走路了三分鐘

步行了三分鐘 is correct, and 步行 here can be replaced with 走.

Comment: thanks for the fast response! is 步行 a common/natural way of speaking or is 走 the best if you wan to say "walking" as a verb?

Comment: both are common and natural.